# Android app crashes when tapping notifications in notification bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I have observed on my tablet that whenever I receive a notification from the app, and I tap the notification, the app crashes when it attempts to load.

I <del>haven't</del> verified this behavior is not present on my phone.

The tablet is a Samsung n5110 running CM11 (4.4.4) M11 with SE app version 1.0.52.

Comment: You should get a notification from this comment (so you can see if it crashes on the phone as well).

Comment: @Howlin Thanks. It did not crash on the phone.

Comment: This occurs in the alpha testing version as well v.1.0.54

Comment: I have this bug on the Nexus-10 with 5.1 (stock), but only in Portrait mode. It does not happen in Landscape mode. It also doesn't happen in 4.1.1 (stock) or 4.4.4 (CM 11) in Portrait (those are Smartphones). The app-version is 1.0.60 on all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about this! It's fixed in the next update. It would've been fixed sooner but it ended up being a lot harder to repro than we expected. Funny enough, there was a comment in the method that was causing it that said `#TODO: Is this going to cause a race condition?`.

This should be fixed in any version of the app greater than or equal to 1.0.64.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it after the next update. Naturally, launching the notification message for this response crashed the app, lol.