# Errors in Alpha version vs Beta version

Tags: support, android-app, bug-reports

What is the etiquette on posting a bug report in the android app (tablet version) in testing (which is available to only those who have joined testing by invitation into google plus group), when the said error occurs in the beta version currently available in the market (the common version for phone and tablet).

For example take a look at this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246138/android-app-crashes-when-tapping-notifications-in-notification-bar).

**Edit**: Clarification:

Many errors in the current beta have been corrected in the alpha version<sup>*</sup>. I want to point out those errors which still remain. But as the errors are likely to e in the beta version too, they might have been pointed out earlier.

So what I am asking is: Should I make a new bug report if I find an uncorrected error in the alpha version? If no, what to do?

<sup>* The alpha version mentioned is the tablet alpha version which is being tested now. It is newer than the beta version of the android app available in the market</sup>

Comment: The alpha version has been released as beta, I think

Answer (score 1):

Errors are still errors. The process is the same for whatever release of the software you're using. Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app).

You should approach this the same way you'd approach asking any other question on any other Stack Exchange site - check if the question already exists, if it does,  comment on it. If it doesn't, post your own.

Comment: I asked this because some errors in the beta are corrected in the alpha

Comment: So, what stops you from posting "hey! I've got this problem! I've tested it in the latest alpha and it works fine but in beta it does <this>"? You know, like you would in any other software development environment...

Comment: It will probably be closed as duplicate, that's why I am asking for what to do

Comment: Also, if it is corrected in alpha version what is the point in pointing it out? As in the next beta release it will be solved

Comment: If there is an existing question stating <your problem> in <your build>, then it would be a duplicate, if you're talking about an issue that's fixed in a newer build than the other version you're testing against then yes, it will probably be fixed in the latest release and you probably don't need to report it again. If you can't find an existing instance of the problem then report it - just like when asking a question anywhere else on the site.

Comment: I clarified further, is my question clear now?